# Continuity conditions in solutions to differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on a small problem.

> Find the solution of the initial value problem $y' = \frac{2x}{1 + 2y}$, $y(2) = 0$ in explicit form and obtain the following solution

$$y = \frac{1}{2} \left(-1 + \sqrt{4x^2-15}\right)$$

The question I'm having is on the domain of validity of the solution. I obtain the interval $\left(\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2},\infty\right) \bigcup \left(-\infty,-\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}\right)$. However, I am told that only the latter interval should be included since the solution should be continuous. May I ask if this is indeed the case, and why so? Thank you.

Comment: I think in the latter interval it should be $-\infty$ which I edit, otherwise it is invalid.

Comment: Why you exclude the points $x=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}$ in the interval?

Comment: putting the values into the original equation gives an undefined equation for the differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval of validity for this IVP is just the interval $(\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2},\infty ) $because it contains the initial condition that $x = 2$. The other interval of validity wouldn't work because your initial condition isn't in that set.

If this were a regular ODE with no specified initial condition, then what you have right now would be the correct intervals of validity.

Hope that helps!

Comment: is the reason why the union of intervals wouldn't work because the solution curve is not continuous? I'm still slightly confused on this point.

Comment: the interval on which this IVP is satisfied needs to contain your initial condition in order to be continuous. the union wouldnt work because the solution would experience a discontinuity at $x=\{\sqrt{15}}{2}$.

Comment: alright, thanks